# Is there a way, in a spring controller, to add objects to a Freemarker Model without @ModelAttribute

Tags: spring, freemarker

I have my MVC view resolver set to Freemarker as normal.  But I want to add a bunch of objects to my model.

Now I know I can do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
```

and that will map parameters and create a User object that gets added to the template marker.  and I know I can do this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model) {
```

Where I can add just about everything I want.  But my question is do I have to do it that way?

I am wondering if there is a way to do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(HttpServletRequest req) {
  MyContext myContext = new MyContext();
  myContext.addStuff(stuff);
  ....  add more stuff
  MagicViewObject.addModel(myContext);
  return "freemarkerTemplate"
}
```

And then have access to the myContext object in the freemarker Template.  Now I know I can probably do this with the @ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model,  but my question is:  is there another way to do it.  I don't like annotations in method signatures.  I'm weird that way.

Comment: Does something like `public String index (Model model) { model.addAttribute("foo", getFoo()); model.addAttribute("bar", getBar()); model.addAttribute("baz", getBaz()); }` not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return an `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView` object.